# visual studio 2010 autogenerated DataSet

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, dataset

When I connect to a database via VS tools it offers to automatically generate the DataSet code for my DB. I didn't work with databases in VS before that way, so can anyone tell, is that autogenerated code is applicable for a serious project, that will need to be maintained later? Or it's good only in simple and common cases and it's better to write my own classes for database interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomand to use ORMs like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) or [Nhibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)

ORMs allow you to abstract from Data base you will work with POCO objects. that will help you in maintain and in design your project.